# How to hide the brackets and hypens in jquery mask on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I dont want to display  the brackets and hypens in my input field on focus. Jquery mask is defaulting it to the format which ever i am giving. How to hide that default property i.e. () and -., but on blur the brackets and hypens should get displayed.

Tried:

```
<input id="ssn"/>
$("#ssn").mask("(999)-999-9999");
```

Demo Link:

[URL](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q6gx/625/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this help you out?

```
$('#ssn').blur(function() {
   $(this).mask("(999)-999-9999");
});
```